# Why can't I output the style tag in my twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, paragraphs

I'm desperately trying to render a style attribute, inside a paragraph's template. But all of these variations:

```
{%
  set backgroundUrl = content.field_slider_background|render|naked|replace({' ': '', "\\n": '', "\\r": ''})
%}


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="background-item" style="background-image: url({{ backgroundUrl }});">
```

,

```
{%
  set backgroundAttributes = create_attribute()
%}

<div{{ backgroundAttributes.addClass('background-item').setAttribute('style', 'background-image: url(' ~ backgroundUrl ~ ')') }}>
```

and even:

`<div class="background-item" style="z-index: 0;">`

and

`<div class="background-item" {{ 'style="...' }}>`

just return `<div class="background-item">`. Other tags are fine.

Does twig generally strip style tags?! Using the latest D8 version...

Edit: outputting `backgroundUrl` actually gives me the correct string, so writing a tag like `data-test="{{ backgroundUrl }}"` works nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done it to print a background color like this in a paragraph template

```
<div class="container color-{{ content.field_text_color[0] }}" style="background: #{{ content.field_card_color[0] }};">
```

And it just worked fine. Can you give us the full template maybe we can figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: i figured so far that the style tag is being remove when i render the paragraph field as a block. im going to open a new question instead. thanks so far!

Comment: if you still want to help me out: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239921/where-and-why-are-style-tags-removed-in-the-render-process

Comment: @Alex, this is the correct answer to the question here, you can use style in templates, but you can't render the paragraph in a block like you do in the follow up question without getting problems with the XSS filter.