# Where and why are style tags removed in the render process?

Tags: theming, blocks

I have a block (in Drupal 8) that renders a field of a node. This is my build function:

```
public function build() {
  $node = $this->getNode();
  $build = array();
  $markup = array();
  $current_lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

  if ($node && $node->hasTranslation($current_lang)) {
    $node = $node->getTranslation($current_lang);
  }
  else {
    $node = false;
  }

  if ($node) {
    $fieldsToRender = array(
      'field_slider',
    );

    $viewmode = 'default';
    $entityType = 'node';
    $display = $this->getEntityViewDisplay();
    $viewBuilder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entityType);

    foreach ($fieldsToRender as $field_name) {
      if (isset($node->{$field_name}) && $field = $node->{$field_name}) {

        $displayComponentSettings = $display->getComponent($field_name);

        if (!is_array($displayComponentSettings)) {
          $displayComponentSettings = array();
        }

        $fieldRenderable = $viewBuilder->viewField($field, $displayComponentSettings);
        if (count($fieldRenderable) &&! empty($fieldRenderable)) {
          $rendered = render($fieldRenderable);

          if ('' !== $rendered) {
            $markup[] = $rendered;
          }
        }
      }  
    }

    if (count($markup)) {
      $build = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => implode("", $markup),
      );
    }
  }

  return $build;
}
```

When I `dpm($rendered)` after `$rendered = render($fieldRenderable);` it gives me the wanted markup, in which at some point **is an inline style tag** that comes from inside a paragraph's template.

For some reason though, the inline style tag is removed in the final block output. I thought it was maybe due to the filters in the `page.html.twig` but just rendering the region using `{{ page.regionname }}` makes no difference.

So, where (and why) does Drupal strip that style tag?

PS: I also noticed in the block version of the field strips the twig debug comments, while the above mentioned dpm output still contains them. So I guess it has something to do with how the block handles the build function's returned markup...

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187765/why-are-twig-template-variables-with-markup-not-being-rendered

Comment: when you use inline_template, the markup is actually converted to text. so you have to use the |raw filter in that template. thanks!

Comment: No, never use the |raw filter. If you don't render early you don't get in trouble, see the answer from @guilhom.

Comment: Yes, raw is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete Clive answer, you could directly use your `$fieldRenderable` variable into a new renderable array that you will return from your `build()` function.

Example (not tested) :

```
$build = [];
foreach ($fieldsToRender as $field_name) {
  // Do your stuff
  $build[] = $fieldRenderable; // you can put whatever you want for the key
}
return $build;
```

The render process is done when you return the `$build` variable.

Comment: this unfortunately doesnt work

Comment: Did you put a key for the new array containing the fieldRenderable ? If $field_name is unique, you can use that and replace $build[] = $fieldRenderable by $build[$field_name] = $fieldRenderable

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i didnt work in the first place because i had that `$rendered = render($fieldRenderable);` put before which appearantly caused issues

Comment: You don't need to call render on it, you only need to return a renderable array here. It will be done for you.