# How to tell my custom block to not use placeholders/ lazy loading?

Tags: views, 8, blocks, caching

I have a custom block that renders a node's field's content. Now, when I type in random text in that field and `kint` in page.html.twig the region in which that block is rendered, the rendered output looks fine.

The problem is, when I embed a view via [token filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_embed_views) in the node field, `kint` just returns a placeholder for my whole block (which eventually has other content than just that one view token).

As a result, I cant figure whether that region actually has content or not since [Themes improperly check renderable arrays when determining visibility](https://www.drupal.org/node/953034) (I cant believe this is still a thing).

So, is there any way I can tell my block or that embedded view to not "use placeholders" but actually have the finished render output when I render it in page.html.twig?

Comment: You use this code to place a node field in a block? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239921/where-and-why-are-style-tags-removed-in-the-render-process - Then add a token filter to the node field and use a view token inside. So you get a lot of custom and contrib code which IMHO is very hard to debug and maintain. And this only to get view results in a block, which views can do out of the box.

Comment: I have a field in which I want to show 3 blocks, 2 of them come from views, the third one embeds a node teaser using my own filter like `[embed:node:22:teaser]`. To have everything nice side by side, I use the 3-col plugin in my ckeditor (based on bootstrap), so customers/ editors can easily place/ change various blocks *in addition* to any free text they like to put there

Comment: So, in my node field I can place 3 different blocks in a bootstrap row, using 3 cols. above and below i can put any other wysiwyg content. if i want, i can change a teaser/ promoted node on the fly.
the alternative would be to programm a block or provide a template for a given block, but changes would have been to make in code rather via backend... and then, still, i wouldnt know if no placeholders would've been used anyways

Comment: Try another approach, use Paragraphs and Bootstrap Paragraphs https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_paragraphs. This has a paragraph type to embed views.

Comment: @4k4 i will have a look into that, thanks! im already using paragraphs for other kinds of fields, maybe this is will help me out :) shouldnt paragraphs have the same issue with views placeholders?

Comment: You should be able to solve all what you've mentioned with these two modules and some theming in twig templates.